# Couldn't get "name" value from json via Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have a problem for getting "ad" value from mysql database.

Here is my listele.php code to get a json format including values.

```
<?php

    //If the values are not blank
    //Connecting to our database by calling dbConnect script 
    include('connection.php');

    Class Kullanici{
        public $id = "";
        public $ad = "";
        public $soyad = "";
    }

    $kl = new Kullanici();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM kullanici";
    $list = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $resultFromSql = mysqli_num_rows($list);
    $sayac = 0;
    echo("[");
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)){
        $sayac = $sayac + 1;
        $kl->id = $result["id"];
        $kl->ad = $result["ad"];
        $kl->soyad = $result["soyad"];
        echo json_encode($kl,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        if($resultFromSql != $sayac){
            echo(",");
        }
    }
    echo("]");
?>
```

When I run the code snippet, I get the json format

```
[{ "id": "27", "ad": "Aslı", "soyad": "Şafak" },{ "id": "29", "ad": "Ali", "soyad": "Ak" },{ "id": "30", "ad": "Ersin", "soyad": "Demir" },{ "id": "31", "ad": "Sercan", "soyad": "Demirbaş" }]
```

When I get these values from json format to insert all them into the listview, "ad" value is null but others have their values.

```
kullanicilist = new ArrayList<>();
        Call<List<Kullanici>> x = Manager.getInstance().goster();
        x.enqueue(new Callback<List<Kullanici>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Kullanici>> call, Response<List<Kullanici>> response) {
                Log.i(LOG,"istek | onResponse  is working");
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    kullanicilist = response.body();
                    Log.i(LOG,"istek | kullanicilist : " + kullanicilist.toString());
                    adp = new KullaniciAdapter(kullanicilist, getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);
                    listView.setAdapter(adp);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Kullanici>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(LOG,"istek | onFailure  is working");
                Log.i(LOG,t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

First Log statement in onResponse

```
I/com.example.dbtojson.activity.MainActivity: istek | kullanicilist : [Kullanici{id='27', isim='null', soyad='Şafak'}, Kullanici{id='29', isim='null', soyad='Ak'}, Kullanici{id='30', isim='null', soyad='Demir'}, Kullanici{id='31', isim='null', soyad='Demirbaş'}]
```

Comment: Can you show Kullanici class which you are using in your android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data you get from server is

```
{ "id": "27", "ad": "Aslı", "soyad": "Şafak" }
```

Data you are printing in retrofit client is

```
Kullanici{id='27', isim='null', soyad='Şafak'}
```

Server is sending value "Asli" in key name **ad**. Your client has member variable **isim** which is a different key name, that's why it is not getting mapped.

In client,

Change your member variable name from **isim** to **ad**

OR

if you are using GSON then put annotation above it.

```
@SerializedName("ad")
String isim
```

This will map value of key **ad** to **isim**